# Add same IBAction to multiple buttons. Latest Xcode, swift 3, iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uibutton, ibaction

Before I used to think this was really trivial... but now I can't seem to do it. I used to create multiple buttons, change their respective tags, then create one IBAction and it'd be called for all my buttons!

However, this was a while ago. Now I am trying to do the same and it doesn't seem to work. No matter what I do, my IBAction seems linked only to one button and it doesn't get triggered by any other.

I tried :

```
@IBAction func myAction(sender: UIButton) { }
@IBAction func myAction(_ sender: UIButton) { }
@IBAction func myAction(_ sender: Any) { }
```

And none of those works. Is this a bug? Is there a new way to do this? Am I forced to create individual actions for every button, despite the functionality of each being really familiar?

I googled and I can't just seem to make this work lol maybe there's something im missing now.

Comment: @dfd I did that through the storyboard. The methods with different signatures was just to try different things, as some other posts suggested. There's literally no real code, I just want to test it out as print(sender.tag) but only one button triggers this IBAction.

Comment: add tag value  to your button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Xcode. Hope apple gets its bugs fixed soon.

The default signature of the IBAction when you drag from button looks something like

```
@IBAction func meHere(_ sender: Any) {
    //something here
 }
```

Now if you add another button and try to set the same IBAction to the button it wont allow (Only apple knows why though)

**Solution :**

Change method signature to

```
@IBAction func meHere(_ sender: UIButton) {
}
```

Change Any to Specific UIComponent. Now control drag from your IBAction to your new button everything will be fine :)

[image]
As you can see both me and you button are hooked to same IBAction :)

[image]
Happy coding

Comment: This! I had tried this already but didn't work, however, I picked up from the first imagine you posted and I could eventually drag the listener to the button. I think that one need to drag from the little (+) sign instead... what a pain. Such small detail lol.

Comment: @fabian-vergara : hahahaha :) am glad you could solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

Change @IBAction func myAction(_ sender: Any) { } to

```
@IBAction func myAction(_ sender: AnyObject) { }
```

So you can link any button to one single IBAction method.

(control + drag your buttons to *"myAction"* method's body in Assistant Editor)